# Why is context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn not generating a cookie?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

We have an MVC 5 application that we have added Web Api Controllers to in order to provide REST API functionality. We have successfully implemented OAuth authentication through the OWIN pipeline using a custom OAuth Provider class.

Now we want to implement authentication cookies as well to protect static resources on the server. I'm sure there's a million other ways to do this, but the request for the resource is a link directly to that resource so I can't use my OAuth token or any other mechanism which is why we want to use cookies...the browser sends them already, no need to change anything.

From everything I've read it is possible to do both Bearer Token authentication and Cookie authentication with the OWIN Pipeline. Basically Web API will use Bearer Tokens cause that's all the client will supply and requests for certain static resources on the server will use Cookies which are sent on all requests.

Our problem is that with the code below an auth cookie is never generated. Throughout the pipeline I never see a **set-cookie** header on the response, which is why I added the Kentor Cookie Saver to the pipeline...it's supposed to help.

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
...
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
...
```

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
...
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
// I was told this might help with my cookie problem...something to do with System.Web stripping Set-Cookie headers
app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
  AuthenticationType = Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
  AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
  ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4)
});
...
```

**Custom OAuth Provider**

```
...
// Creates our claims and properties...keep in mind that token based authentication is working
CreatePropertiesAndClaims(acct, out properties, out claims);
if (IsAccountAuthorized(claims))
{
  AuthenticationProperties authProps = new AuthenticationProperties(properties);
  ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
  claimsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);

  AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, authProps);
  context.Validated(ticket);

  ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
  context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookieIdentity);    // This should create the auth cookie!??!
}
else
{
  context.SetError("Unauthorized", "You don't currently have authorization. Please contact support.");
}
...
```

Keep in mind that Token based authentication is working so I assume it's a configuration setting missing or misconfigured, or a pipeline ordering issue.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late answer, but we came across exactly the same problem. My colleague and I spent 4 hours trying to figure out why. Here is the answer that hopefully can save somebody else from bang their head against the wall.

Inspect the response,  you can see there is `Set-Cookie:.AspNet.Cookies=LqP1uH-3UZE-ySj4aUAyGa8gt ....` But the cookies it is not saved. What you need to do is, in your ajax call, include credentials.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
)
```

we are using the Fetch API, it looks like the following

```
fetch(url, {  
  method: 'post',  
  headers: {  
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  
  }, 
  credentials: 'include'  
})
```